# Getting Permission denied when trying to setup rTorrent with lighttpd

Tags: networking, server, permissions, bittorrent, rpc

I want to create locally a rTorrent RPC server.

I installed rTorrent, here is `~/.rtorrent.rc`

```
download_rate = 500
#upload_rate = 150

directory = ~/torrent/data

session = ~/torrent/session

port_range = 6881-6999
port_random = no

check_hash = yes

schedule = watch_directory,15,15,load_start=~/torrent/torrent_active/*.torrent

dht = auto

dht_port = 6880

encryption = allow_incoming,require,require_rc4

scgi_local = /home/vinz243/torrent/rpc.socket
```

and my `lighttpd.conf`:

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_redirect",
#       "mod_rewrite",
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www/html"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80


index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
## Use ipv6 if available
#include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"


include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"

server.modules += ( "mod_scgi" )
scgi.server = (
                "/RPC2" =>
                  ( "127.0.0.1" =>
                    (
                      "socket" => "/home/vinz243/torrent/rpc.socket",
                      "check-local" => "disable",
                      "disable-time" => 0,  # don't disable scgi if connection fails
                    )
                  )
              )
```

When I run rTorrent it runs correctly I just have those lines at the bottom:

```
(20:00:31) Using 'epoll' based polling.
(20:00:31) Using 'epoll' based polling.
(20:00:31) Using 'epoll' based polling.
(20:00:31) Closed XMLRPC log.
```

However when I try in my browser to go to`localhost/RPC2`,
Here is `/var/log/lighttpd/error.log`:

```
2015-12-23 19:45:08: (log.c.164) server started 
2015-12-23 19:45:29: (mod_scgi.c.1393) connect failed: 7 Permission denied 13 0 /home/claire/torrent/rpc.socket 
2015-12-23 19:45:29: (mod_scgi.c.2410) fcgi-server disabled:  0 /home/claire/torrent/rpc.socket 
2015-12-23 19:45:29: (mod_scgi.c.2790) all handlers for  /RPC2 on /RPC2 are down. 
2015-12-23 19:45:30: (mod_scgi.c.2108) fcgi-server re-enabled:  0 /home/claire/torrent/rpc.socket 
2015-12-23 19:45:35: (mod_scgi.c.1393) connect failed: 7 Permission denied 13 0 /home/claire/torrent/rpc.socket 
2015-12-23 19:45:35: (mod_scgi.c.2410) fcgi-server disabled:  0 /home/claire/torrent/rpc.socket 
2015-12-23 19:45:35: (mod_scgi.c.2790) all handlers for  /RPC2 on /RPC2 are down. 
2015-12-23 19:45:36: (mod_scgi.c.2108) fcgi-server re-enabled:  0 /home/claire/torrent/rpc.socket 
2015-12-23 19:45:45: (mod_scgi.c.1393) connect failed: 7 No such file or directory 2 0 /home/claire/torrent/rpc.socket 
2015-12-23 19:45:45: (mod_scgi.c.2410) fcgi-server disabled:  0 /home/claire/torrent/rpc.socket 
2015-12-23 19:45:45: (mod_scgi.c.2790) all handlers for  /RPC2 on /RPC2 are down. 
2015-12-23 19:45:46: (mod_scgi.c.2108) fcgi-server re-enabled:  0 /home/claire/torrent/rpc.socket
```

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

### Correct answer

To solve the problem just add this to your `rtorrent.rc`:

```ini
schedule = scgi_permission,0,0,"execute.nothrow=chmod,\"g+w,o=\",/home/user/rtorrent/rpc.socket"
```

### Old answer with history

rTorrent is weird.. After start it **changes the access rights of socket** file, making it unaccessible for lighttpd.

I am experiencing the same problem, and currently I just run

```
chmod 777 /home/vinz243/torrent/rpc.socket
```

every time, after rtorrent starts, but I think, `chmod 777` is not a better solution.

There is github-issue : https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/issues/394

Hope, it could be helpful for you.

**UPD** : seems, like it is a typical problem of the bare rtorrent-instalation.

To solve the problem just add this to your `rtorrent.rc`:

```ini
schedule = scgi_permission,0,0,"execute.nothrow=chmod,\"g+w,o=\",/home/user/rtorrent/rpc.socket"
```